# Is there a way to unwrap from optional variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Is there a way to "unwrap" variables returned by `reload` method?

```js
let reloadProps: ReloadProps | undefined;

if (useClientSide() === true) {
    reloadProps = reload(props.eventId);
}

const {
    isTiketAdmin,
    jwt,
    userFbId,
    organizationId,
    organization,
    event,
    enableSaleSwitch,
    enableSaleSwitchOnWordpress,
    permission,
} = reloadProps;
```

Now I got this error:

```
./pages/[lang]/event/[...eventId].tsx:72:5
Type error: Property 'isTiketAdmin' does not exist on type 'ReloadProps | undefined'.

  70 |   }
  71 |   const {
> 72 |     isTiketAdmin,
     |     ^
  73 |     jwt,
  74 |     userFbId,
  75 |     organizationId,
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: `if (reloadProps) { ... }`? Right now that will clearly fail if `useClientSide` returns false, for example. If reload always returns an object in the client-side case, why use reloadProps at all, for that matter; just do `if (useClientSide()) { const { isTiketAdmin, ... } = reload(props.eventId); ... }`.

Comment: Why not to wrap it inside a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is, that the values you want to get out of `reloadProps` are not available if is `undefined`. You have to check that the value is not `undefined` beforehand:

```
if (reloadProps !== undefined) {
  const {
    isTiketAdmin,
    jwt,
    userFbId,
    organizationId,
    organization,
    event,
    enableSaleSwitch,
    enableSaleSwitchOnWordpress,
    permission,
  } = reloadProps;
}
```

This way the compiler can infer, that the type is not `ReloadProps | undefined`  anymore but `ReloadProps` only and then you can access the values.

Comment: Will values available out of if statement?

Comment: No. Out of the if statement `reloadProps` is `undefined`. Therefore no values.

Comment: @János const (like let) is _block_ scoped, so no. I'd strongly recommend getting familiar with basic JavaScript before trying to add the complexity of TypeScript and a framework like Next.js on top.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to check `reloadProps != null` so that null and undefined are checked? Or better yet just `if (reloadProps)`

Comment: @TheN3wbie Yes, definitely. Good catch!